# Replacing System` definitions in a context whilst still maintaing acces to them

Tags: variable, contexts, system, system-variables

Given the system operator `TensorContract` I can define a new one,  `TensorContractLazy` with the attribute  `HoldAll`, which does some some optimizations, but whose definition still depends on the original `` System`TensorContract ``  for some cases.

If I load old programs, however, they will not benefit from this because they do not use `TensorContractLazy`. I would like, if possible, in the current namespace, a way for my function, `TensorContractLazy`, to be called instead of `` System`TensorContract `` when evaluating `TensorContract`. This would allow old programs to be run with this new definition without changing them.  However. I'm not sure if this is possible, or how it could be done.

Comment: You can try `Block` the codes like `Block[{TensorContract= TensorContractLazy},codes]`

Comment: `Module` works better than `Block` here because `Module` does not replace  the original `TensorContract` used in the definition of `TensorContractLazy` . However, it would be nice to be able to execute the old codes with `TensorContractLazy`, and  without having to surround them with a `Module`.

Comment: Yes. That will work. I just need to change the Attributes of the function along with the $overwrite variable when in the block.